# Getting questions from past 90 days in Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm no SQL Server expert, but I believe the following should work:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM Posts
WHERE CreationDate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
```

Unfortunately in [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/) all I get is:

```
'NOW' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

I'm sure I'm just using completely the wrong syntax, but I can't even find any documentation for DE. Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: `DATE_SUB`, `NOW()` and `INTERVAL` are not functions in SQL Server - try this instead - http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/462567

Comment: I see. It appears they are MySQL functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using functions that aren't available in SQL Server.  You'll need to look at using [`DateAdd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) instead. You can use something like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/462567):

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM Posts
WHERE CreationDate > DateAdd(day, -90, getdate());
```

You can look through the SQL Server documentation on MSDN to help writing queries and to be sure that you're using the correct functions.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful information. I'll check MSDN.